# Get value from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I have a MongoDB collection with structure like in the image below.[image: collection structure]

I want to console log the value of `item`. So, I want to console log "journal". How can I do that? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It seems you are unfamiliar with how to use MongoDB. Please read their docs https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/ or learn from any other tutorial.

Comment: it seems like you are using mongoDB compass, which is just DBMS, and console log is a JS command , what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    db.collection('collection_name').findOne({
        _id:ObjectId("61412a7bf30b9 .... ") /// doc _id
    }).then(r=>{
      console.log(r.item)
    });
});
```